# no guarda en la base de datos utilizando php,js,postgresql

Tags: php, javascript, postgresql

Una pequeña duda al momento de guardar un dato en la base de datos usando php y Js. Primera vez haciando esto de esta manera

esta es la funcion que hace al momento de darle click al boton de agregar

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#guardarcontrato').click(function(){
          contrato=$('#contrato').val(); hora_1=$('#hora_1').val(); hora_2=$('#hora_2').val();hora_3=$('#hora_3').val(); 

          agregardatos(contrato,fec_1,hora_1,hora_2,hora_3);

        });
      });
    </script>
```

Busca la funcion de agregardatos y deberia decirte que se guardo exitosamente o no (pero creo que no esta llegando a este punto ya que no envia la alerta)

```
function agregardatos(contrato,hora_1,hora_2,hora_3){

    cadena="contrato=" + contrato +
            "&hora_1=" + hora_1 +
            "&hora_2=" + hora_2 +
            "&hora_3=" + hora_3 +

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"agregardatos.php";
        data:,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('#tablac').load('tablac.php');
                alertify.success("agregado con exitos");
            }else{
                alertify.error("fallo el servidor");
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Y esta es la de agregardatos.php donde deberia conectarse a la base de datos y guardarlos

```
<?php
$conex = pg_connect ("host=localhost port=5433 dbname=*** user=p**** password=*****");

$v_contrato=$_POST['contrato']

$v_hora_1=$_POST['hora_1'];

$v_hora_2=$_POST['hora_2'];

$v_hora_3=$_POST['hora_3'];


$sql= "INSERT INTO hora(contrato,hora_1,hora_2,hora_3) VALUES($v_contrato,$v_hora_1,$v_hora_,$v_hora_3)";
  }
}
  $result = pg_Exec($conex, $sql);
```

Comment: A la clave data no le estás pasando un valor o si?

Comment: ¿Todos son valores numéricos?

Comment: En tu  "$.ajax" en la parte de "data" prueba a colocar esto:  data:{"contrato":contrato,"hora_1":hora_1 ,"hora_2":hora_2 ,"hora_3":hora_3},

Comment: si todos son valores numericos

Comment: mmmm okok, dejame probar